# Span buttons to opposite sides using css only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

[image: Modal with buttons]

I have these two buttons on my modal which let the user next step or restart the form progress.

I want to switch span these buttons to the full width of the modal and I tried the following code:

```
<div className="form-button">
  <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-width-75 reset-button" onClick={this.resetFilter.bind(this)}><img alt="Revise recommendations" src="/img/icons/redo.svg" className="button-image"/>Restart</button>
  <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-width-75 next-button" onClick={this.nextButton.bind(this)}>Next<i className="icon-right"></i></button>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
.form-button {
  width: 500px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin:0px auto;
}

.reset-button {
  float: left;
}

.next-button {
  float: right;
}
```

My expected output is:

```
|| <RestartButton>      --modal width--          <NextButton> ||
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What's with the `className`s? The attribute is `class`.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb please ignore `className` it's just because I'm using React for my front-end with mixins, sorry should've clarified earlier

Comment: Well, changing the `className` to `class` worked in the fiddle.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb just saw your fiddle, seems to be working. I guess it means the problem is not with the css of these specific elements but probably something else overriding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `className`s to `class`es, and it will work: https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/yndrnvvo/

```
<div class="form-button">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-width-75 reset-button" onClick={this.resetFilter.bind(this)}>Restart</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-width-75 next-button" onClick={this.nextButton.bind(this)}>Next<i class="icon-right"></i></button>

</div>
```

Comment: I checked my code, actually I was overriding the css because of the css that was being applied on every secondary button because of my modal. I guess that makes your answer the correct answer :P

Answer (score 0):

```css
.form-button {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-button">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-width-75 reset-button" onClick={this.resetFilter.bind(this)}>
    <img alt="" src="/img/icons/redo.svg" class="button-image" />Restart</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-width-75 next-button" onClick={this.nextButton.bind(this)}>Next<i className="icon-right"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```